# implementing closure in authManger.Login wapper function to Alamofire authenticate?

Tags: swift, http, authentication, closures, alamofire

I have created this static function Login to wrap Alamofire authenticate function. I have one problem how to implementing closure with Alamofire authenticate and how to call it in action asynchronous. any help will be appreciated :)

```
    static func Login(username:String, password:String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ response: DataResponse<Data?>?) -> ()) {

        var response:DataResponse<Data?>?

        AF.request("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(username)/\(password)")
            .authenticate(username: username, password: password)
            .response { resp in
                response = resp
                completion(true,response)
        }

        if(response?.response?.statusCode == 200)
        {
            completion(true, response)
        }
        else {
            completion(false, nil)
        }
    }

code from action outlet 
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    AutheManager.Login(username: newAccountName, password: newPassword) { (success, response) in
        if (success  == true)
        {
            // rest of code 
        }
        else 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `completion` is wrong. It should be inside the `completion` block as below,

```
static func Login(username:String, password:String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ response: DataResponse<Data>?) -> ()) {

    Alamofire.request(URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(username)/\(password)")!)
        .authenticate(user: username, password: password)
        .responseData { (response) in
           if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
               completion(true, response)
           } else {
               completion(false, nil)
           }
    }
}
```

Above is compilable example with latest `Alamofire` where i changed `DataResponse<Data?>?` to `DataResponse<Data>?` and `.response` to `.responseData`. If you have an older version that change the required method signatures.